# No UMS support - Radeon 3450

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I just performed a clean install of 14.04 on my Dell Vostro 420 with Radeon 3450.  I get to grub, click to boot with Ubuntu, and then black screen.  If I boot in a recovery mode with low graphics mode, it gives me some trouble but eventually loads the home screen although a bit distorted.  I've found the following error:

```
[    0.745320] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    0.781219] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    0.781267] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[   34.279595] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[   34.279645] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[  143.571802] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[  143.571819] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

I've searched the threads and have seen others post about this issue but can't seem to figure out what to do next, at least from those other posts.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, thankfully I ran into this problem via running Ubuntu from a live USB rather than wiping my system. I used the `nomodeset` boot parameter, and saw that error message before it booted to a completely black screen. My graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 7660G and I'm having the issue with Ubuntu 15.10 (so they still have not fixed it for your case most likely)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know LB.  I won't upgrade.  I've been booting in recovery mode then resuming normal boot which seems to work.  I occasionally have issues with the system freezing but don't know if it's related to the graphics card.  Cheers.